# How to set keydown event in document click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented document on click function and I need to also set event on clicking ENTER.

My click document click function:

```
$(document).on('click', '#customButton', function(evt) {

  // this implementation refresh my page
  $(document).on('keydown', '.current', function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) { // If Enter key pressed
      $('#customButton').click();
    }
  });
});
```

HTML code on I implement my Javascript:

```
<form  method="post" class="newsletter">
    <div class="current">
        <div class="fce-newsletter-form">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
                    <h2 class="mb-half newsletter-title"><?php the_sub_field('newsletter_title')?></h2>
                    <p class="mb-2 lead">Mit unserem Newsletter erhalten Sie monatlich Informationen rund um das Urlaubsland Österreich und eine Auswahl exklusiver Angebote und Gutscheine!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="testFormChange">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="name_Validation" type="email" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail Adresse *" required/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <input type="button" class="fce-newsletter-form-button btn btn-block btn-primary" id="customButton" value="Weiter">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="step1" name="step">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <p class="fce-newsletter-form-note">mit * gekennzeichnete Felder bitte ausfüllen.</p>
                    <p class="fce-newsletter-form-error-message"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="form_step" class="form_step" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, inside function you can see my testing "keydown" function, but when I press ENTER, page is refreshed and I can not change document on click funtion. Any advices, please?

Comment: Without referring to what you think is wrong with your code, can you explain what you are trying to do?  The code doesn't make sense currently, as you create a click event handler so that when the button is clicked you then create a keydown event handler.  Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that `keydown` and  'click' event should be handle separately.

You can prevent any default event by [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault);.
In you case it is with if keyCode == '13'

```js
$(document).on('click','#customButton', function (evt) {
    alert("button clicked");
});
    
 // this implementation refresh my page
$(document).on('keydown','.current', function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) { // If Enter key pressed
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#customButton').click();
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  method="post" class="newsletter">
    <div class="current">
        <div class="fce-newsletter-form">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
                    <h2 class="mb-half newsletter-title"><?php the_sub_field('newsletter_title')?></h2>
                    <p class="mb-2 lead">Mit unserem Newsletter erhalten Sie monatlich Informationen rund um das Urlaubsland Österreich und eine Auswahl exklusiver Angebote und Gutscheine!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="testFormChange">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-8">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="name_Validation" type="email" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail Adresse *" required/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4">
                                    <input type="button" class="fce-newsletter-form-button btn btn-block btn-primary" id="customButton" value="Weiter">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="step1" name="step">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <p class="fce-newsletter-form-note">mit * gekennzeichnete Felder bitte ausfüllen.</p>
                    <p class="fce-newsletter-form-error-message"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="form_step" class="form_step" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rarely correct to bind one event handler inside another. The way you've written it, the `keydown` event handler isn't created until the user clicks on the button. So they have to click on the button, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to invoke the second handler.

Define them separately.

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.current', function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) { // If Enter key pressed
        $('#customButton').click();
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#customButton', function(evt) {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: I tried that, with ENTER my page is still refreshed and I can not change HTML code...

Comment: If you don't want submitting the form to refresh the page, you can add a `submit` handler to the form that uses `evt.preventDefault()` to prevent submission.